Java SSLSocket find out if client sent a certificate
My application allows authenticated and non-authenticated TLS connections and in the code, I need to distinguish between them (just as in authenticated and non-authenticated HTTPS sessions).
Is there a way to find out if a Java SSLSocket connection (on the server) was established from a client with a client certificate? And if so, can I see the CN= of the client certificate?

Yes, use SSLSocket.getSession().getPeerCertificate().

@user207421 Perfect - Exactly what I was asking for. My application allows authenticated and non-authenticated TLS connections and in the code, I needed to distinct between them (similar to authenticated and non-authenticated HTTPS sessions)

@Abra It is not 'similar to authenticated and non-authenticated HTTPS sessions'. It is exactly the same thing. You've done enough damage here already. Please leave it alone.

As noted in the comments,
try {
    Certificate cert = socket.getSession().getPeerCertificate();
    // we get here if the client *was* authenticated
    return cert;
} catch (SSLPeerUnverifiedException e) {
    // we get here if the client *was not* authenticated
    return null;
}

seems to be what you need.
